# Retrieve gameserver POST message with TcpListener

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

I'm trying to receive data from a Counter-Strike game server. This game server does a http POST to a specified IP:PORT every X seconds with data. I'm trying to catch this data with a TCPListener, but the function crashes after a few seconds after displaying the data.

This is my code:

```
Imports System.Net
Imports System.Net.Sockets

Public Class Form1
    Dim Listener As TcpListener
    Dim port As Integer = 90
    Dim localAddress As IPAddress = IPAddress.Parse("192.168.1.34")
    Dim bytes(9000) As Byte

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        StartProcess()
    End Sub

    Private Sub StartProcess()
        Listener = Nothing
        Try
            Listener = New TcpListener(localAddress, port)
            Listener.Start()
            While True
                Dim client As TcpClient = Listener.AcceptTcpClient()
                Dim stream As NetworkStream = client.GetStream()
                Dim i As Integer = stream.Read(bytes, 0, bytes.Length)
                While (i <> 0)
                    TextBox1.AppendText(System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes, 0, i))
                    i = stream.Read(bytes, 0, bytes.Length)  //<-HERE IS THE ERROR
                End While
                client.Close()
            End While
        Catch ex As Exception
            Listener.Stop()
            MsgBox("Stop")
        End Try
    End Sub
End Class
```

POST data seems to come in multiple chunks or pages:

First Page:

```
POST / HTTP/1.1
user-agent: Valve/Steam HTTP Client 1.0 (730)
X-LogBytes-BeginOffset: 0
X-LogBytes-EndOffset: 8781
X-Tick-Start: 89
X-Tick-End: 90
X-SteamID: [A:1:4260888584:24478]
X-Server-Addr: 82.223.49.142:30015
X-Timestamp: 10/13/2023 - 11:12:33.636
X-Server-Instance-Token: a387dbb5945b983b
Content-Type: text/plain
Host: 123.123.123.123:90
Accept: text/html,*/*;q=0.9
accept-encoding: gzip,identity,*;q=0
accept-charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8,*;q=0.7
Content-Length: 8781
```

Second Page:

```
10/13/2023 - 11:02:07.782 - server_cvar: "sv_tags" "16k,CS2,Dust2,casual,espa??a,only,spain"
10/13/2023 - 11:02:07.782 - server_cvar: "sv_tags" "CS2, espa??a, spain, Dust2, 16k, only, casual"
10/13/2023 - 11:02:07.782 - Log file started (file "logs/2023_10_13_110208.log") (game "csgo") (version "9842")
10/13/2023 - 11:02:07.782 - Loading map "de_dust2"
10/13/2023 - 11:02:07.782 - server cvars start
10/13/2023 - 11:02:07.782 - "tv_enable_dynamic" = "false"
10/13/2023 - 11:02:07.782 - "tv_enable" = "false"
10/13/2023 - 11:02:07.782 - "tv_enable1" = "false"
10/13/2023 - 11:02:07.782 - "tv_relaypassword" = ""
10/13/2023 - 11:02:07.782 - "tv_password" = ""
10/13/2023 - 11:02:07.782 - "tv_advertise_watchable" = "false"
10/13/2023 - 11:02:07.782 - "sv_cheats" = "false"
10/13/2023 - 11:02:07.782 - "sv_debug_overlays_broadcast" = "false"
10/13/2023 - AND SO ON...
```

Any clue to fix the error? Also, I think I'm missing more pages of data.

Thank you!